# How to write this type of format in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I want to include the outlines in the left side of my slide in bemaer like given in this figure can please suggest me how to do this [image]

Similarly on the left hand side of every slides
[image: Introduction]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bar on the left side of each slide containing the sections of the presentation, with the current section highlighted by a different font color, can be achieved using `\useoutertheme{sidebar}`.

If you're also interested in the background color and other design elements of the presentation you show in your question, you might want to try `\usetheme{Hannover} \usecolortheme{crane}`.

Here is a useful [beamer theme gallery](https://deic-web.uab.cat/%7Eiblanes/beamer_gallery/index.html) that can help identify beamer themes.